# How do you cite a reference in a comment?

Tags: support, comment, markdown, hyperlinks

If I want to quote a reference in an answer on this site, I use the syntax `[Here][1]` followed at  the end of the answer by `[1]:URL`.
[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Haddock)  is an example.
But this doesn't work in the comments. What should I do instead ?

Answer (score 16):

You should use the following format:

```
[text](link)
```

e.g.

```
[Google](http://www.google.com/)
```

See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links).

Comment: Georges: In fact, the same format works in posts, comments, as well as in chat.

Comment: [Let's see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Haddock). Yes, it works: fantastic! Thanks a lot to both of you, Zev and @Srivatsan, for  helping me so quickly. I'll use that format everywhere now.

Comment: By the way, this does not work on mathoverflow, does it? How can you do it over there?

Comment: @Rasmus: you can't. (Prettified) Hyperlinks in comments is not supported in the version of StackExchange software running on MathOverflow. You should instead just paste raw links into the comment.

Comment: See http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/295/markdownstyle-links-in-comments/#Item_0 and http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/464/syntax-for-link-in-comment/#Item_0

Comment: [Google](http://www.google.com/)   is definitely a [magma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)).

Answer (score 2):

I will add that this information is shown when you click on "help" while writing a comment. (See the picture below. Similar picture can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/how-to-use-formatting-in-comments/77500#77500).)

> Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: `[link](http://example.com)` `_italic_` `**bold**` `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work. [Learn more](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

[image: screenshot with comment help]

If you then click on "learn more", you will get to the section of the MarkDown help concerning comments: https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting